# How to integrate this function of bessel integration form?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration, bessel-functions

Thank you for reading my question!

As we know, the first kind Bessel function of 0th order can be integrated as follows
$$
J_0(x) =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-ix\sin{(a+\tau)}}d\tau =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-ix\sin{\tau}}d\tau, a\in R
$$
The constant $a$ will not change the value. The reason is explained by [@GEdga](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/442/gedgar) in the comment.

However, this is the case for the following integration
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-ix\sin(\tau+a)}d\tau
$$
Setting $x=1$, by the matlab code following, the absolute value would change with different $a$

```
int_func = @(x) exp(-1j*1*sin(x));
int_result = zeros(1,100);
x = linspace(1,100)/100*pi*2;
for i = 1:100
    disp(x(i));
    int_result(i) = integral(int_func,0+x(i),pi+x(i));
end
figure(1);
plot(x,abs(int_result),'LineWidth',1);
grid on;
xlabel('a');
ylabel('Integration result (abs)');
```

How can I get the analytical formula for this integration?

Thank you! Any help is appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Integral $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-ix\sin{(a+\tau)}}d\tau$ does not depend on $a$ because the integrand $e^{-ix\sin{(a+\tau)}}$ is periodic with period $2\pi$ and we integrate on an interval of length $2\pi$.

Comment: For $T(a) := \int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-ix\sin(\tau+a)}d\tau$, Maple has
$T(0) =  \pi J_0(x) + i \pi H_0(x)$ and $T(\pi/2) = \pi J_0(x)$ but does not evaluate $T(\pi/3)$.

Comment: @GEdgar 
That's right. I tried Mathematica and I got the seem result you mentioned.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Too long for a comment.*

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-ix\sin(\tau+a)}\,d\tau$$

I faced the same integral quite recently but it was for small values of $a$ and $x$.

To solve the problem, I used a series expansion around $a=0$ and obtained

$$I=\pi  (J_0(x)-i \pmb{H}_0(x))+ix \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{\frac{n+2}{2}}\,P_n(x)\,a^{2n}$$ where the first polynomials are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(x) \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & \frac{1}{12} \left(x^2+1\right) \\
 3 & \frac{1}{360} \left(x^4+10 x^2+1\right) \\
 4 & \frac{1}{20160} \left(x^6+35 x^4+91 x^2+1\right) \\
 5 & \frac{1}{1814400} \left(x^8+84 x^6+966 x^4+820 x^2+1\right) \\
 6 &  \frac{1}{239500800} \left(x^{10}+165 x^8+5082 x^6+24970 x^4+7381 x^2+1\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

For sure, I took into account the fact that $\Re(I)=\pi  J_0(x)$ does not depend on $a$.

Comment: Thank you, Claude! This helps.